# Adjusting a grid cell's dimensions to match the img child element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to keep the original width/height of my img while it's in a grid cell, but I also want the div, which is holding the img, to adjust its height based off the image.

```
<div class="hero">

    <!-- ommited other level elements --> 
    <div class="map">
        <img src="Assets/Map.svg">
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.hero {
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 80px;

    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "text   text   map"
        "logo   logo   logo";

    padding: 40px 130px;

    border: 20px solid #242DFE;
}

.map {
    grid-area: map;
}
```

I've tried setting the height of the map class to min-content, but the div was still not the same height as the image.